# HP Loadrunner - Read every web_custom_request response

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I have a script code with multiple (about 200) call of type:

`web_custom_request(...)`

I'm using the following code to read the `JSON` response of some ones:

```
web_set_max_html_param_len("999999");

web_reg_save_param("JsonData8",
    "LB=",
    "RB=",
    "Search=Body",
    LAST);
```

Is there a fast method in order to read the response of each `web_custom_request(...)` without copy and paste the code for each line?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I sure hope you are reusing your variables or you are going to have one honking large memory footprint virtual user at the end of every iteration.

As to your need to "read" the response.   Be careful on how much you read, just pulling out the information you need without pulling the whole response and then parsing it locally.   The reading of the entire response and with local processing expands your resource envelope along several axis': Memory, CPU and potentially disk as well if your virtual users start swapping out due to large memory footprints.  This will crush the performance of your load generator and color your timing record results due to slow code execution

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to reduce the amount of code, look at doing 200 iterations of a request instead.

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
   lr_save_int(i,"loopnumber");

   web_reg_save_param(lr_eval_string("JsonData{loopnumber}"),
   "LB=",
   "RB=",
   "Search=Body",
   LAST);

   web_custom_request(...)
}
```

Just remember that storing 200 JSON responses in different variables will take up a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to capture the responses for debugging (or) script enhancement purpose try using extended log options.
- In other side during load tests also you want to capture all responses consider James Pulley suggestions